# Why is this happening on CodeBlocks?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

So I get the following error when I build with CodeBlocks:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
```

My command is

```
int 41,42
```

And I get this error! 
What does it mean?

Btw, My full command line is

```
#include <iostream> using namespace std; 
int 41,42;  
int main() {  
    cout<<43+44<<endl;
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Please show more of your code. The line that throws the error, and enough code around it to get the context. See [mcve] for details.

Comment: Btw, My full command line is #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int 41,42;

int main()
{
    cout<<43+44<<endl;
    return 0;
}

Comment: #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int 41,42;

int main()
{
    cout<<43+44<<endl;
    return 0;
}

Comment: Please edit the question and post the code there. What do you expect `int 41,42` to do?

Comment: For future reference, CodeBlocks is an IDE. Think of it like a fancy notepad. What matters is the compiler which is the one turning your code into a program. Most likely CodeBlocks uses gcc as compiler.

Comment: bruh i am so dumb nvm

Answer (score 1):

You should post a little bit more of your code, but it looks like you are trying to declare an integer without an identifier.
You have to give a name when declaring a variable.
An example might be:

```
int x = 41;
int y = 42;
```